# Pull-Request auto-complete doesn't automatically complete when all requirements are met - Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

To keep it short, I'm using a script in Azure DevOps that generates a pull request automatically every time a new branch is pushed to the repository. 
Said script enables the pull request "auto-complete" funcionality, which lets me merge code using GIT after I complete all the branch policies. I have only one branch policy enabled, which compiles my code and checks whether it should complete the pull request or not, based on the pipeline compilation results.
Everything was working fine before one week ago, people pushed their branches normally and ADO automatically created the PR, build checked, merged and auto-completed the PR, as my only branch policy had always been met. 
Now even all branch policies are met, the PR is stuck and won't auto-complete for some reason, even after the build compilation turns out as success and there are no merge conflicts.

If I click on approve, it then begins to complete automatically as it should. However, this manual step was never necessary for the PR to finish, nor I have a branch policy that demands an approval to complete the PR. 
This is affecting all the projects in my ADO organization, so it may not be a configuration problem.
Maybe anyone has stumbled across the same problem?

Edit: Microsoft is looking at the issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Pull-Request-doesnt-automatically-compl/10082816

Comment: (Not an answer, just a comment why I removed a tag: Git has neither PRs nor approvals; so this is exclusively an add-on from AzDO.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [link provided in the question](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Pull-Request-doesnt-automatically-compl/10082816), this issue apepears to have been fixed on Jul 28, 2022

"Microsoft Solution - Feedback Bot
Closed - Fixed
We have released a fix for this issue! Thank you for providing valuable feedback to help improve the product."

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the user account has the permission: [Bypass policies when completing pull requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-permissions?view=azure-devops).

Comment: I've checked, all my current users (including admins) have "Bypass policies when completing pull requests" on deny.